# How to apply Wait strategy in case it's not working always?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, sapui5, webdriverwait

We are having intermittent failures on the waits, although we have already applied, implicit //wait when we launch the url, fluent wait, and explicit wait for a few elements and even we //have used thread.sleep function as well as a couple of places where the other 3 (selenium //waits) don't work.

```
We are having intermittent failures on the waits, although we have already applied, implicit //wait when we launch the url, fluent wait, and explicit wait for a few elements and even we //have used thread.sleep function as well as a couple of places where the other 3 (selenium //waits) don't work.
//When an element loads slowly, especially for asserting alert pop-up message validations?
`//Case 1:-> For implicit wait 
//below code launch the application.**your text**
public class BrowserOperations
{
    WebDriver driver;


    public WebDriver LaunchApplication(String browserName) throws Exception
    {   
        System.out.println("Browser \""+browserName+"\"");
        switch(browserName)
        {
        case "Chrome":
            
            DesiredCapabilities jsCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            //chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
            //chromeOptions.addArguments("--incognito");
            Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
            prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "en-US");
            chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
            jsCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
            
                        
            Map<String, Object> prefsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
              prefsMap.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
              prefsMap.put("download.default_directory", PropertiesfileDataProvider.GetPropertyValue("DownloadPath"));

            chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefsMap);
            // need to uncomment below line for headless option
            if(PropertiesfileDataProvider.GetPropertyValue("headless").equals("Yes")) {
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless=new");
                System.out.println("With headless browser");
            }else
                System.out.println("No headless browser");
            
            driver=new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); 
            
            break;


driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
          System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize());
          driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1440, 1024));
          System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize());
         
         System.out.println("URL: "+PropertiesfileDataProvider.GetPropertyValue("URL"));
        driver.get(PropertiesfileDataProvider.GetPropertyValue("URL"));
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
        return driver; 

//Case 2:-> explicit wait 
//example login detail function through which user enters the details and enter to application
public void enterLoginDetails(String username, String password) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(240));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(textbox_Username));
        textbox_Username.sendKeys(username);
        textbox_Password.sendKeys(password);
        button_Login.click();
        BaseClass.logger.info("Logged in to application");
        System.out.println("Logged in to application");
        selectInterfaceLanguage();
    }


//case 2:-> fluent wait 
//Below is the fluentwait which is written to handle different conditions 
public void fluentwaitWithExpectedCondition(String expectedCondition, WebElement element) {

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(180))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
//Below are the conditions on which element will be actions
        switch (expectedCondition) {
        case "clickable":
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
            break;
        case "visible":
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
            break;
        case "stateToBe":
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementSelectionStateToBe(element, false));
            break;
        case "invisible":
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element));
            break;
        default:
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        }

    }

//below is my test script

@Test

public void testcaseaut() 
{
        try {
            
            LoginWithUser();//Login function which uses browser operation class to launch the url for specific browsers.
            if (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains(env1) ||           driver.getCurrentUrl().contains(env2)) 
            { 
            NavigateTofeature(); // funtion to navigate to feature which is written in the same class
            createAndDeleteUser("Ramana", "xuz", "ramanaaddfeature@xyz.com");// function to create user
            featurePageObj.clickOnfeaturefMenu();
            featureOBJ.clickOnUserdownloadInfoFromaddfeatureMenu();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            Assert.assertTrue(featureOBJ.VerifyUserIsPresentOndownloadInFoPopUp("ramanaaddfeature@xyz@gamil.com"));
            Thread.sleep(500);
            featureOBJ.checkboxSelectAllPresentOndownloadUserInfoPopUp();
            Thread.sleep(500);
            featureOBJ.clickdownloadButtonOndownloadUsersInfoPopup();
            featureOBJ.clickYesButtonOnConfirmAction();
            logger.pass("User clicked on yes button for confirm action popup");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            featureOBJ.clickviewJobLogsButtonOnJobStatusPopUp();
            logger.pass("User clicked on view job logs button for job status popup");
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            applyFilterForUserOnLogScreenForJobTypeUserInfodownload();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            logScreenForJobTypeUserInfodownloadAndClickOnDisplayLogForFirstRow();
            infoMessageOnMessageTabForUserInfodownload();
            infoMessageOnFilesTabForUserInfodownload();
            jobLogObj = new addfeatureUserJobLog(driver);
            String dateVar=jobLogObj.returnDateFieldInFormatFromFilesDisplayLogForUserdownloadLikeDisplayedOnlocaiInfoPopUp();
                        clickOndirectoryAndSelectWorkspaceThanNavigateTorequired();
            featureOBJ = new requiredPage(driver);
            featureOBJ.VerifyrequiredPage();
            //driver.navigate().refresh();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            featureOBJ.clickOnaddfeatureMenu();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            featureOBJ.clickOnUserprocess();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            //test case steps to verify that recovery date displayed for a user that is deleted and downloaded
            featureOBJ.clickAndSendValueToSearchFieldOnlocaiUsersInfoPopup("ramanaaddfeature@xyz@gamil.com");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            //jobLogObj = new addfeatureUserJobLog(driver);
            jobLogObj.verifyenddateDateIsDisplayedOnlocaiUserInfoPopUp(dateVar);
            jobLogObj.clickOnCancelButton();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            createAndDeleteUser("Bamana", "addfeature", "bamanaaddfeature@xyz@gamil.com");
            featureOBJ.clickOnaddfeatureMenu();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            featureOBJ.clickOnUserprocess();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            //test case steps to verify that recovery date should displayed for a user that is deleted and downloaded
            featureOBJ.clickAndSendValueToSearchFieldOnlocaiUsersInfoPopup("bamanaaddfeature@xyz@gamil.com");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            //verifyenddateDate
            jobLogObj.verifyenddateDateNotDisplayedOnlocaiUserInfoPopUp(dateVar);

            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Not applicable for remaining urls");
            }
          
            
        } catch (AssertionError error) {
            logger.fail(error.getMessage());
            logger.fail(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(error));
            Assert.fail(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(error));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("Catch Block");
            logger.fail(exception.getMessage());
            logger.fail(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception));
            Assert.fail(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exception));
        }
}`
```

The above code is trying to run script "testcaseaut

--

```
type here
```

- 

", with some supportive functions, which are given in the above code.
and code is explained.
We are trying to ask that why the wait stretagy is not working.

Comment: don't mix implicit and explicit waits.  (remove: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(60)); )   You also won't need those sleeps once you've implemented proper webdriverwaits.  (or the FluentWaits... WebDriverWaits are pre-configured FluentWaits, so you don't have to deal with those at all...)

Comment: See here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/  Going forward you should try/catch all your method calls that use the webdriverwaits so you can include the exceptions your receive in more targeted, future questions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying,
I have tried removing implicit from the code, and running the script with only using explicit wait either for visible condition or for clickable condition with Duration of 120 sec

but my tests are intermittently failing (like out of 5, 2 time it fails at the same place where I put explicit wait) but if I apply Thread.sleep for few seconds, it works.

```
public void ClickWorkspace() throws Exception
{
   commonFunctionsObj.WaitUntilTextToBePresentInElement( workSpace, "some 
     text");
    String 
 workspace=commonFunctionsObj.GetWorkspaceAccordingtoEnvironment();
//Required the changes as per the number of workspace increased and with 
the below code 
//we can filter the required workspace and perform operations
workspace_Header.click();//clicking on the column name workspace which will 
open a filter (input box)
BaseClass.logger.pass("Clicked on filter by workspace");
System.out.println("Clicked on filter by workspace");
WebElement eleFilter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='class1 
class2']"));

try {
    eleFilter.isDisplayed();
} catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
    BaseClass.logger.info("Not clicked retrying.........");
    workspace_Header.click();
}
 // Thread.sleep(2700);
 commonFunctionsObj.WaitUntilVisibilityOfElement(eleFilter);
 commonFunctionsObj.WaitUntilElementIsClickable(eleFilter);
 eleFilter.sendKeys("="+workspace);//giving value to filter box
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='class1 
 class2']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

 // This below code failing intermittently
           **// Thread.sleep(2700);
           commonFunctionsObj.WaitUntilVisibilityOfElement(eleFilter);
           commonFunctionsObj.WaitUntilElementIsClickable(eleFilter);**
```

The above place it fails intermittently. What could be wait strategy for this. Any lead would be great help.
Thanks in Advance.